# Why can't I display data getted with $http.get?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I try to get data in api and I get object in console.log like this :

```
Object {_id: "590c14b1bf38e524e4b1a1ca", name: "John", age: 22, __v: 0}
```

Here is my code I use to get it and display .

server

```
detailRoute.route('/detail/:name')
           .get(function(req,res) {
                User.findOne({name:req.params.name},function(err,user) {
                    console.log(user);
                    if (err){
                        res.status(404).send(err);
                    }else{
                        res.status(200).json(user);
                    }
                })
           });
```

js:

```
var vm = this;
            vm.dt =[];
            vm.getDetail = function() {
                $http.get('/api/detail/' + $stateParams.dt , $stateParams.dt)
                    .then(function(response) {
                        vm.dt = response.data;
                        console.log(response.data);
                    });
            };
            vm.getDetail();
```

html:

```
 <ul ng-repeat="d in vm.dt"> 
<li>{{d.name}}</li> 
<li>{{d.age}}</li>
 </ul>
```

And nothing display . I try change to

```
vm.dt.push(response.data)
```

And it worked . So I want ask why my code above not work . Thank for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the output of your `http` call is an object.
you're overriding your existing array reference `vm.dt` to an object inside the callback, then trying to loop over an array inside the template.

try to change the `ng-repeat` in a dictionary way.

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.dt"> 
 <li>{{key}} {{value}}</li> 
</ul>
```

> I try change to vm.dt.push(response.data) And it worked.

because in this way you still using an array, and the ng-repeat will work

to filter only name and age you can use an `ng-if` or a custom filter

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.dt" ng-if="key === 'name' || key === 'age'"> 
 <li>{{key}} {{value}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank man , it work but it show all item in obj . How can I show only name and age

Comment: Thank you . It's is good way , but I still confused . Imagine if I have more than 10 or 20 key in obj . So I will try write 10 or 20 times . Is there any better way

Comment: yes this is a fast way to filter, you can filter the object inside your javascript and keep only the fields you want. or use a custom angular filter after the ng-repeat

Comment: thank you . last question . What is the way better for performance between write filter to display and use `vm.dt.push`

Comment: i would push the result inside the array and keep the array style ng-repeat then inside the ng-repeat block you can print the fields you want (keeping less code as possible, no ng-repeat, no ng-if)

Answer (score 1):

We have two options for ng-repeat:

1. Object
2. Array

If you are using an `object` inside `ng-repeat` then you need to use it something like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in vm.dt">  
   <li> {{ key }} : {{ value }}</li>  
</ul>
```

And if you are using `array` inside `ng-repeat` then you can do like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in vm.dt">  
    <li>{{ d.name}}</li> 
    <li>{{ d.age}}</li> 
</ul>
```

Now understand what is happening here, you are getting a response from server which is an `object` and you are assigning this `object` to a variable and trying to print it like an `array` but don't forget it is an object so it is not printing.

When you are doing `vm.dt.push(response.data)` you are pushing your object into an array and now you are doing it right. So it is printing your data.

I hope this will help.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

If you want specific fields to display, you should go with `vm.dt.push(response.data)` and then use it

```
<ul ng-repeat="d in vm.dt">  
    <li>{{ d.name}}</li> 
    <li>{{ d.age}}</li> 
</ul>
```

You can see in this code, you no need to filter anything you are just printing the data which you want to display. So as of my understanding, it is good from the performance point of view.

Comment: Thank you , it help me so much . I want ask a question , If I do it i should write custom filter to display exactly i want . So what is the way better for performance between write filter to display and use `vm.dt.push`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `controllerAs` synthax:.

`var vm = this;` means that you should use the **controller alias name** in your view (this does not mean it is `vm`).

Here is an example here the controller alias is `main`:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <ul ng-repeat="d in main.dt"> 
    <li>{{d.name}}</li> 
    <li>{{d.age}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I know it , and in html I use `MainCtrl as vm` . It work well when I change to `vm.dt.push(response.data)`